# How to process an attribute value by a component

Tags: angular, pipe

Let's say I have a very basic component that adds functionality to a given text. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-clickable-key',
  template: '<span (click)="doSomething()">{{ key }}</span>',
  styleUrls: ['./translated-text.component.scss']
})
export class TranslatedTextComponent {
  @Input() key: string;
  
  doSomething(): void {
    this.key = `${this.key} clicked!`;
  }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
<app-clickable-key key="Hello!"></app-clickable-key>
```

Now I would like to append the above functionality not only to tree nodes but also to attribute values:

```
<3rd-party-input customLabel="How to make this clickable as well?"></3rd-party-input>
```

...Which is essentially just a wrapper of a `label` (`<label>{{ customLabel }}</label>`)

If this functionality was only for a transformation of the text, then I would be able to use pipes, but in this case, I need to change the template of that placeholder. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: what do you mean by change the template for placehoder?

Comment: In that particular example, yes, but I assume that this isn't a good example because the template of an input placeholder is controlled by the browser. I'll edit my question.

Comment: yes that is possible, you can create your own input using `ControlValueAccessor` and can setup a wrapper to the actual input

Comment: @noamyg It is unclear, can you please elaborate more with good example of whats going wrong and whats expected?

Comment: @PankajParkar nothing goes wrong. I just want to add functionality to the label of an input (in the above example), given that the label itself is set by data binding and not by content

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be adding behavior to the element. For such a case, I would suggest you extract your functionality in a reusable Directive. The behavior can be attached to any DOM easily.

A directive can be pretty simple, it can use `textContent` `HostBinding` decorator, and returned value will be set to DOM node `innerText`. Just make sure while using directive pass attribute value to it. For eg `clickable="key"` indicate a directive to read the initial value from `key` attribute.

**Directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickable]',
})
export class ClickableTextComponent {
  @Input() clickable: string;
  private text = '';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostBinding('textContent') get textContent() {
    return this.text;
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  doSomething(): void {
    this.text = `${this.text} clicked!`;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.text = this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute(this.clickable);
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<span 
  clickable="key"
  key="Something is funny">
</span>

<hr />

<label
  clickable="customLabel"
  customLabel="This is label working with Directive"
>
</label>
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzewqx)

Answer (score -1):

For that you can use the control value accessor

```
<app-custom-input
  label="My Custom label"
  [(ngModel)]="inputOne"
></app-custom-input>
```

Create component with providers

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.scss'],

  // Step 1: copy paste this providers property
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is complete [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-simple-example-tsm-behxnx)

Comment: I'm unsure, how custom `formControl` can help here to figure out what OP has been asking ?